# What makes Crystal (or SQL Server 2012) shorten strings from a database and how to prevent it?

Tags: sql-server-2012, crystal-reports-2011

What might cause the following and how can I prevent it?

A command object in the Crystal 2011 “database expert” was something like

```
Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J from ……
```

As I was fiddling with format and parameters, Crystal started chopping off **A** after seventeen characters.  The truncation was visible early on, in the “browse data” function of field explorer.

After about a half-hour of trying to figure out why, I gave up and added a needed data item:

```
Select A, B, C, D, E, F, XXX, G, H, I, J from ……
```

**A** went back to normal but **B** started getting truncated.

So I added a fake item at the end

```
Select A, B, C, D, E, F, X, G, H, I, J, 'Nil' as Nil from ……
```

and **B** went back to normal !

Comment: **C** wasn't being used, but after adding 'Nil' on the end, I put **C** on the report.  Sure enough, it is truncated at 17 characters!  This oddity has survived a morning reboot every day for at least a week.

Comment: Without touching the command object, I changed the data location to another copy of the database on a different server.  Now all three **A, B, and C** are truncated.  Could it be SQL Server and not Crystal?

Comment: After a while, it started working right again.